# Correct direction for sleeping?

Tags: scripture, identification-request

As per [this article](https://www.sleepfoundation.org/sleeping-positions/best-direction-to-sleep) on correct direction of sleeping:

> **Which Direction Is Best to Sleep in?**
>
> According to ancient traditions like **vastu shastra**, the best direction to sleep in is toward the south. This theory is also supported by some recent research1. This means that when you lie in bed, your head is pointed south2, and your feet are pointed north.

As highlighted in above quote the claim is made based on vastu shastra that one should put their head to the south when sleeping. However the exact reference is not given. Can somebody help in validating this statement?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why not sleep with your head facing North direction?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2804/why-not-sleep-with-your-head-facing-north-direction)

Comment: Do you want from Vaasthu sastras only?

Comment: As far as I heard (not came across shastra yet), south is the direction of Yama, bhairava & Pitras, thus while sleeping head is kept in South, to not offend trios. Also, keeping head in South while sleeping, is said to confer good health & Aishwarya. Those who wish to gain knowledge just like students must sleep keeping head in East & legs towards west. Since, Suryanarayana & Chandra arise from east. Surya controls Prana, & Chandra controls the mind, which r the basic requirment for a student to be active & sharp.

Comment: @hanugm yes. Vastu shastra only